# Create table from two column arrays

Tags: matlab

I have two column arrays with the same number of rows:

```
>> size(values)
ans =
       12915           1
>> size(positions)
ans =
       12915           1
```

`values` contains some NaN entries:

```
>> sum(isnan(values))
ans =    
        2500
```

while `positions' is filled with integer values:

```
>> sum(isnan(positions))
ans =
     0
```

Some values in the two arrays:

```
values(randi(length(values), 10, 1))
ans =
    0.0290
    0.1000
    0.0430
       NaN
    0.0310
    0.9700
    0.3170
    0.1750
       NaN
    0.1410

positions(randi(length(positions), 10, 1))
ans =
     5
     8
    12
    11
    10
     6
    10
     3
     9
     4
```

If I try and create a `table` with those two columns I get an uncomprehensible (for me) error message:

```
>> table(values, positions)
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
```

I tried and removed the NaN values without success: I keep getting the same error message. However, I cannot understand the error message.

What's the problem?

Comment: The `values` look like ratios. Are you sure you are not dividing anything by zero there? I had that issue a couple of days ago. You can check if there is division by zero using `max(values)`. If it returns `Inf`, then you divided something by zero.

Comment: check if `exist('table', 'var')` yields 1, if yes, then you should clear the variable with name `table`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have very likely created a variable called `table`. If you type `whos table` you will probably get a result such as:

```
whos table
  Name       Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes    
  table      1x1                 8  double
```

You can solve this by simply clearing the `table` variable: `clear table`. This will leave the function but delete the variable.

Note that you have created the `table` variable somewhere, thus it's likely that you also use it somewhere (especially if you have a large project with mostly scripts and not functions). Just deleting the variable may result in a broken code. Therefore, I suggest you search for the variable name in your scripts and make sure you don't break anything.

Comment: Yes, that was the case. I was working on a very complex script that I received and I did not notice that 'table' was already defined. Having myself been working mostly on other programming languages for the past years, I am used to 'reserved' keywords which matlab is weirdly missing. Thanks for your kind answer.

Answer (score -2):

The table(a,b) notation indexes the matrix table with a, and b. Since your values are non-integer, you get this error message.
I suppose, what you intend to do is to merge the two column vectors. For this you can use [ ], as

> table = [values positions]

This will still contain nan values, but I guess this will not bother you

CORRECTION

If however you would like to add the values in table at their position, you may use

> table(positions)=values

Comment: That is simply wrong: table is a valid function in MATLAB and what you are proposing is only true if `table` was defined as a variable.

Comment: @RobertStettler it's only wrong for versions of MATLAB newer than R2013b.